# Change the default path from Public folder to a folder inside Module in Zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, filepath

I have a module which contains all the js,images, audio etc. inside the module. But by default, the default path is set to

> localhost/Zend/public

As a result, I am forced to keep everything in that Public Folder only. I want to change that path to Module Directory. My baseUrl gives me the default path. How do I change this path?

Comment: You should totally use this module! https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager

Comment: This is not for self use. I want this module to be avaialble to users using Zend Framework. So, I want to have minimum extra additions for them. Is there a way so that the path is set inside the module without using another module?

Comment: Users should never be allowed to write files into your modules surely!

Comment: Or do you mean people developing with zf2 using the particular module?

Comment: If the later I have only come across to ways when using other peoples modules which are add a module such as this as a dependency of your module in composer.json or tell people to copy the assets to your public folder in the README. But sure there are other solutions

Comment: I mean people developing Zf2 based sites who would like to implement my module.

Comment: People developing Zf2 based sites who would like to implement your module are probably going to want to install it with composer. Composer will resolve your modules dependencies (such as assetmanager) for the end user, if you're looking for least effort on their part, that's the way to go. Create a composer package for your module, and just make assetmanager, and whatever else you need, dependencies declared in your modules composer.json file.

Comment: Thanks! I will give a read about this.